# Dagger official example for Binding Instances problem

Tags: dependency-injection, annotations, dagger-2

I'm new to dagger. I was following the documentation at https://dagger.dev/dev-guide/ and when it comes to Binding Instances section, here's the example provided:

```
@Component(modules = AppModule.class)
interface AppComponent {
  App app();

  @Component.Builder
  interface Builder {
    @BindsInstance Builder userName(@UserName String userName);
    AppComponent build();
  }
}
```

My question is where's this `@UserName` coming from?
The explanation leading to this code block is

> Perhaps your app takes a single argument representing the user’s name that you’d like to inject as @UserName String. You can add a method annotated @BindsInstance to the component builder to allow that instance to be injected in the component.

I couldn't reason about it. Can anyone shed some light?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@Username` in this example is a **Qualifier**. If you were to use/inject a plain `String` it'd clutter things up quite a lot (since `String` is a somewhat common type), but in combination with a qualifier `@Username String` becomes a unique key.

`@Named("foo")` is a basic qualifier included that you can use, or you can just create your own—e.g. `@Username`

Comment: any guide on how to create a self defined Qualifier?

Comment: @woodybird You add `@Qualifier` to your annotation. There's also an example on the Dagger documentation that you linked